# How can I validate an input for ip address in angular?

Tags: angular

So I am reading an existing code and we have a form with an ip address input field. Requirement here is that the input must only take in numbers.

A brief segment of the HTML looks like this:

```
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <label for="ipaddress" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">IPV4 Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        id="ipaddress" name="ipaddress" formControlName="ipaddress" required>
      <div class="invalid feedback" *ngIf="">
         Invalid Ip address entered.
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

TS looks like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.buildForm()
 }

//Using form builder
 buildForm() {
 this.form = fb.group({
 id: null,
 ....
 ...
 ipAddress: ['', [Validators.required]]
});
```

Your help will be gladly appreciated, Thank you :'(

Comment: How have you attempted to implement the custom validator?  A simple regex validator would do the trick -- there's plenty of regexes for validating ipv4 or ipv6 (tho they're much more complicated than the ones shown here in the answers here.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas So I called a function from my custom validator in my TS. The function from my custom validator is the validator function Christian commented but I am getting Provider Errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To accomplish what you looking for you can create a custom validator.

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  //Using form builder
  buildForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: null,
      ipAddress: ["", [Validators.required, customValidator()]]
    });
  }

  get ipAddress(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get("ipAddress") as FormControl;
  }
}
```

```
export function customValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    const regex = /^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/;

    if (regex.test(control.value)) {
      return null;
    }

    return { ipError: true };
  };
}
```

```
<div class="form-group row" [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label for="ipaddress" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">IPV4 Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      id="ipaddress" name="ipaddress" formControlName="ipAddress" required>
        <div class="invalid feedback" *ngIf="ipAddress.errors && ipAddress.errors.ipError">
            Invalid Ip address entered.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a stackblitz with the same implementation:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4rueag?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I called that `customValidator` and pass it together with `Validators.required`.
To check if it is a valid ip address i test it with regex.

If **something** as an object is returned from the custom validator then it appears as a error for that control, otherwise if `null` is returned then it passes :)

Sorry for my bad english...

Hope you understand and it helps.

Comment: Please include your code in the answer itself and not on a random external site.

Comment: Christian, I tried your method putting the getIpAddress in my numbersOnly directive class and calling the function in my TS (for "best practices" sake). I am getting this error "Error: StaticInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for OnlyNumbersDirective"

Comment: @ChristianGustavo This helped a lot and moved me to the right direction. Thanks Christian!

Comment: Awesome, i'm glad that it helped. Can you post your code that is throwing this error?

Answer (score -1):

I have took the Christian example and added a directive to only accept numbers and dot "."

Also modified the regex expression because in Christian example "999.999.999.999" this is valid, and this is not correct.

Html:

```
<div class="form-group row" [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <label for="ipaddress" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">IPV4 Address</label>
    <input type="text" OnlyNumbers class="form-control" placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      id="ipaddress" name="ipaddress" formControlName="ipAddress" required>
    <div class="invalid feedback" *ngIf="ipAddress.errors && ipAddress.errors.ipError">
      Invalid Ip address entered.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ValidatorFn,
  Validators
} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  //Using form builder
  buildForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: null,
      ipAddress: ["", [Validators.required, customValidator()]]
    });
  }

  get ipAddress(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get("ipAddress") as FormControl;
  }
}

export function customValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    const regex = /^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;

    if (regex.test(control.value)) {
      return null;
    }

    return { ipError: true };
  };
}
```

OnlyNumbersDirective:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[OnlyNumbers]' })
export class OnlyNumbers { 

    @Input() permitirDecimales: boolean = true;
    @Input() allowSign: boolean = false;
    @Input() decimalSeparator: string = '.';

    previousValue: string = '';

    // --------------------------------------
    //  Regular expressions
    integerUnsigned: string = '^[0-9]*$';
    integerSigned: string = '^-?[0-9]+$';
    decimalUnsigned: string = '^[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?$';
    decimalSigned: string = '^-?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?$';

    /**
     * Class constructor
     * @param hostElement
     */
    constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) { }

    /**
     * Event handler for host's change event
     * @param e
     */
    @HostListener('change', ['$event']) onChange(e) {

}

/**
 * Event handler for host's paste event
 * @param e
 */
@HostListener('paste', ['$event']) onPaste(e) {

    // get and validate data from clipboard
    let value = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    e.preventDefault();
}

/**
 * Event handler for host's keydown event
 * @param event
 */
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {

    let cursorPosition: number = e.target['selectionStart'];
    let originalValue: string = e.target['value'];
    let key: string = this.getName(e);
    let controlOrCommand = (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true);
    let signExists = originalValue.includes('-');
    let separatorExists = originalValue.includes(this.decimalSeparator);

    // allowed keys apart from numeric characters
    let allowedKeys = [
        'Backspace', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Escape', 'Tab'
    ];

    // when decimals are allowed, add
    // decimal separator to allowed codes when
    // its position is not close to the the sign (-. and .-)
    let separatorIsCloseToSign = (signExists && cursorPosition <= 1);
    if (this.permitirDecimales && !separatorIsCloseToSign ) {

        if (this.decimalSeparator == '.')
            allowedKeys.push('.');
        else
            allowedKeys.push(',');
    }

    // when minus sign is allowed, add its
    // key to allowed key only when the
    // cursor is in the first position, and
    // first character is different from
    // decimal separator
    let firstCharacterIsSeparator = (originalValue.charAt(0) != this.decimalSeparator);
    if (this.allowSign && !signExists &&
        firstCharacterIsSeparator && cursorPosition == 0) {

        allowedKeys.push('-');
    }

    // allow some non-numeric characters
    if (allowedKeys.indexOf(key) != -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A and Command+A
        (key == 'a' && controlOrCommand) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+C and Command+C
        (key == 'c' && controlOrCommand) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+V and Command+V
        (key == 'v' && controlOrCommand) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+X and Command+X
        (key == 'x' && controlOrCommand)) {
        // let it happen, don't do anything
        return;
    }

    // save value before keydown event
    this.previousValue = originalValue;

    // allow number characters only
    let isNumber = (new RegExp(this.integerUnsigned)).test(key);
    if (isNumber) return; else e.preventDefault();
}


/**
 * Get key's name
 * @param e
 */
getName(e): string {

    if (e.key) {

        return e.key;

    } else {

        // for old browsers
        if (e.keyCode && String.fromCharCode) {

            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case   8: return 'Backspace';
                case   9: return 'Tab';
                case  27: return 'Escape';
                case  37: return 'ArrowLeft';
                case  39: return 'ArrowRight';
                case 188: return ',';
                case 190: return '.';
                case 109: return '-'; // minus in numbpad
                case 173: return '-'; // minus in alphabet keyboard in firefox
                case 189: return '-'; // minus in alphabet keyboard in chrome
                default: return String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the live example:

https://angular-ivy-36xqcf.stackblitz.io

Here is the code example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-36xqcf?file=src/app/onlynumbers.directive.ts

Comment: Code should be in the answer itself not on some random external site.